# Failed to inject @Resource Annotation in managed bean

Tags: spring, managed-bean

im trying to inject an util class to managed bean using spring @Resource Annotation,but when i run the application,i get this error.

```
    Caused by: com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name com.web.bean.Bond is not bound in this Context
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.Tomcat6InjectionProvider.inject(Tomcat6InjectionProvider.java:84)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.injectResources(BeanBuilder.java:205)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name com.web.bean.Bond is not bound in this Context
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:770)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.DefaultAnnotationProcessor.lookupFieldResource(DefaultAnnotationProcessor.java:278)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.DefaultAnnotationProcessor.processAnnotations(DefaultAnnotationProcessor.java:187)
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.Tomcat6InjectionProvider.inject(Tomcat6InjectionProvider.java:82)
```

my spring configuration

```
 <context:annotation-config/>
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.web.bean"/>
```

Managed bean where i use the annotation

```
  package com.web.bean;
  @ManagedBean
  @SessionScoped

@Resource
private MailSender mail;
```

Comment: Are you sure? This is not ejb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have fixed this issue without using @Resource Annotation

```
private MailSender mail = (MailSender) SpringWrapper.getInstance().getBean("mail");
```